# Quais são as diferenças entre Assincronismo, Paralelismo e Multithread?

Tags: terminologia, multithreading, assincronismo, paralelismo

As vezes os termos *Assíncrono*, *Multithread* e *Paralelismo* aparece sempre que faço uma pesquisa relacionada a multiprocessamento ou algo relacionado. Entretanto, eu tenho uma dificuldade de entender quais as diferenças entre eles e quais características esses termos tem em comum.

## Questões

- Quais as diferenças entre Assíncrono, Multithread e Paralelismo?
- Quais as características entre Assincronismo, Paralelismo e Multithread?

Comment: Este vídeo também pode ajudar https://youtu.be/zLfXPSeCkB8

Comment: Paralelismo é o resultado alcançado de duas ou mais tarefas (sequências de instruções) executando ao mesmo tempo e sem gargalos, ou seja, em paralelo, qualquer que seja a forma de fazer. Quando o número de tarefas é superior ao de unidades de processamento esse paralelismo pode ser simulado alternando-se entre elas segundo critérios de escalonamento, mas atingir esse resultado ainda depende da forma como isso é programado e do tipo de tarefas sendo executadas e sua relação.

Comment: Assincronismo geralmente se refere a uma forma de programar usando algum recurso da linguagem para "disparar" a execução de uma tarefa longa em paralelo à atual que a chamou e em seguida continuar a atual sem ficar aguardando a longa/demorada terminar. Essa forma de execução é chamada de "assíncrona". Quando ambas as tarefas são breves não há necessidade disso e elas podem ser síncronas, ou seja, executadas em sequência, como duas funções sendo chamadas de forma normal uma após a outra (cada uma "bloqueia" até terminar de executar e passar o controle para a próxima).

Comment: Concorrência e programação concorrente dizem respeito à disputa por acesso simultâneo (concorrente) a recursos compartilhados por múltiplas tarefas e a mitigação de problemas relacionados a isso, questão comum em paralelismo e multi-threading. Uma fora de resolver é usando mecanismos que o SO fornece para isso, como locks (travas), monitores e semáforos, permitindo o acesso individual controlado e deixar outros interessados em fila de espera aguardando a vez.

Comment: Por fim, multi-threading e programação multi-thread dizem respeito a uma forma concreta de se permitir paralelismo e assincronicidade num mesmo processo (programa em execução), próxima a como o SO trabalha (threads de usuário e de kernel). Isso pode ser programado assim diretamente, via threads, ou abstraído mediante algum recurso de assincronicidade fornecido pela linguagem, por exempo o `async` (que pode estar usando threads por debaixo do pano). Paralelismo e assincronicidade valem para processos também, mas por haver isolamento de  memória a comunicação envolve mecanismos de IPC do SO.

Comment: Por fim, um problema frequente em assincronismo é o resultado da execução da tarefa longa precisar ser consumido de uma forma que possui relação com a tarefa que o havia requisitado (a que havia disparado essa execução). Por exemplo precisar ser devolvido a essa mesma tarefa ou tratado por um callback determinado pela mesma. Isso pode ser resolvido de diferentes formas, conforme o mecanismo sendo utilizado (multi-thread, async, funções de callback passadas por argumento ao mecanismo que está promovendo a assincronicidade, etc.).